# How make a callback with factory

Tags: angularjs

Here is a method of my angular controller :

```
            $scope.callJersey = function(shows) {
            var selectedShows = [];
            var show;
            for (show in shows) {
                var temp = {};
                temp.name = show;
                temp.properties = shows[show].selectedShow;
                selectedShows.push(temp);
            }
            addShowsFactory.save(selectedShows);
        }
```

My factory :

```
services.factory('addShowsFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/easyshow/api/shows/add', {}, {
        save: {
            method: 'POST',
            isArray: true
        }
    })
});
```

How can I make a callback when the save method have done his job ?
I tried several ways to display an alert (later will be a redirection) but nothing worked.

Comment: Why dont you return `$http` if its a post call and then when the `promise` is returned , you can redirect

Comment: i'm beginner with angular. After some research, i made this and it worked so i didn't touch it since.

Answer (score 0):

Let me proof `$promise` with some test code

```js
angular
  .module('shows', ['ngResource'])
  .factory('addShowsFactory', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/easyshow/api/shows/add', {}, {
      save: {
        method: 'POST',
        isArray: true
      }
    })
  });

describe("Shows", function() {
  beforeEach(module("shows"));

  it("adds shows", inject(function(addShowsFactory, $httpBackend) {
    var stubMovies = [{name: 'some name'}, {name: 'some other name'}];
    
    $httpBackend.expectPOST("/easyshow/api/shows/add").respond(201, stubMovies);
    
    addShowsFactory.save().$promise.then(function(shows) {
      expect(shows[0].name).toBe(stubMovies[0].name)
    })
    
    $httpBackend.flush();
  }));
});
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

`addShowsFactory.save` return **promise**, you can access it by `$promise` property, then you can call `then` method on it.

[AngularJS documentation and exemple for $promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#user-resource)

Comment: Thx, it's something like that. But I have an error => cannot read property then of undefined.

I had all the dependencies

Comment: @Skulker what `console.log(addShowsFactory.save(selectedShows))` returns?

Comment: it return []. An empty array. Then i have another log. request failed 500. 
[]
angular.min.js:99 POST http://localhost:8080/easyshow/api/shows/add 500 (Request failed.)But i see the data coming to my java part. and the objects are created in my database.

Comment: @Skulker first try to solve problem with **error 500** then we can try to investigate what happened with $promise property

Comment: There is no error my data are send to my backend. it just a log. Is it bad the console log return an empty array ?

Comment: @Skulker - does your backend returns correct headers, for e.g. 201 - new content created? There is nothing bad to logs empty array : )
In other hand, change value for many shows should create **PUT** instead of **POST** as POST is for creating one new entity.

Comment: I'm  using a jersey implementation after the post. Here is the prototype of the called method : public void addShows(List<ScannedShow> body)   This method is for adding as many shows as the body contains. so a post isn't correct ?

Comment: @Skulker - hen should we use PUT and when should we use POST - http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/

Comment: I think we are going in the wrong way ^^. The problem is I want to to do something after the addShowsFactory.save(selectedShows); finished his job but the promise is empty and don't recognyze the then method

Comment: @Skulker I've provided test to proof that `.$promise` exists, what can I do more for you? Check for any error in console, attach screenshot to question

Answer (score 0):

Afters some tests, this is a working solution :

```
                $http.post('/easyshow/api/shows/add', selectedShows).then(
                    function(data){
                        alert("Yes");
                    }, function(data){
                        alert("No");
                    });
```

But because of the status code 500 always returned, only the error function is called. never surrender !!